# Protractor/Cucumber: Select dynamically the first available day on the calendar - the promise is not resolved

Tags: typescript, protractor, cucumber

I want to make a function that will select dynamically the first available (not disabled) day in the calendar. But, after running the test, the first two steps are ok, but after the third step I am getting an error 
"Error: function timed out, ensure the promise resolves within 60000 milliseconds". I cannot figure it out why the promise is not resolved.

Any other ideas on how to select the first available day?

```
When('I select the return date', async () => {
    await calendar.returnDate.click();
    await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(calendar.searchBtn));

    await calendar.days.each(el => {            //calendar.days are all td in the calendar element.all(by.tagName("td"));
        el.getAttribute("class").then(function (attr) {
          console.log(attr);
            if (attr !== "is-disabled") {      //the disabled days in the calendar are having class="is-disabled"
            el.click();
           }
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a return statement in your step definition after your all steps get executed.

```
When('I select the return date', async () => {
  await calendar.returnDate.click();
  await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(calendar.searchBtn));
  let enabled_day = element.all(by.id('your locator')).filter(e=>e.isDisplayed()).first();
  return enabled_day.click();
})
```

If you want to check isDisplayed property of an array of web elements use the filter method and later take the first web element which is displayed.

And don't forget to add a return statement and a expect statement at the end of step definition.

```
filter(filterFn: (element: ElementFinder, index?: number) => boolean | wdpromise.Promise<boolean>): ElementArrayFinder;
(method) ElementArrayFinder.filter(filterFn: (element: ElementFinder, index?: number) => boolean | promise.Promise<boolean>): ElementArrayFinder
```

Apply a filter function to each element within the ElementArrayFinder. Returns a new ElementArrayFinder with all elements that pass the filter function. The filter function receives the ElementFinder as the first argument and the index as a second arg. This does not actually retrieve the underlying list of elements, so it can be used in page objects.

```
@alias — element.all(locator).filter(filterFn)

@view

<ul class="items"> <li class="one">First</li> <li class="two">Second</li> <li class="three">Third</li> </ul>

@example

element.all(by.css('.items li')).filter(function(elem, index) {
  return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
    return text === 'Third';
  });
}).first().click();

// Or using the shortcut $$() notation instead of element.all(by.css()):

$$('.items li').filter(function(elem, index) {
  return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
    return text === 'Third';
  });
}).first().click();
```

@param filterFn
Filter function that will test if an element should be returned. filterFn can either return a boolean or a promise that resolves to a boolean

@returns
A ElementArrayFinder that represents an array of element that satisfy the filter function.